# Not able to play .h264 video on OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, h.264

I captured a standard video from camera of Raspberry pi. The codec of the file is h264.
To play the video I do:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('foo.h264')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Video starts But stops after sometime throwing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "play_video.py", line 9, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: /home/nikhil/Downloads/opencv-2.4/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3739: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

My machine has Ubuntu 12.04. I played an .avi file it plays smoothly. Is the problem with the .h264 or with the OpenCV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop should check that `frame` is not-empty, and not that the video was opened successfully - this check should be done just once at the beginning.
When the frame *after* last is read `frame` is empty and you are then trying to convert it to gray.

Comment: Actually needed to check the `ret` value. At the end of video it becomes `False`so had to break from the loop.

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant.